# Understanding the GAME_AUTOROTATION setting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

This should be seemingly obvious and simple, but it isn't for me and seems to be more confusing than you'd think at first.

The Cocos2d template's GameConfig.h I have set the following:

```
#if defined(__ARM_NEON__) || TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationNone

// ARMv6 (1st and 2nd generation devices): Don't rotate. It is very expensive
#elif __arm__
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationNone

// Ignore this value on Mac
#elif defined(__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED)

#else
#error(unknown architecture)
#endif
```

In the App Delegate `applicationDidFinishLaunching` I have this:

```
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
#else
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
#endif
```

In the RootViewController `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`:

```
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION==kGameAutorotationNone
    //
    // EAGLView won't be autorotated.
    // Since this method should return YES in at least 1 orientation, 
    // we return YES only in the Portrait orientation
    //
    return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
```

So despite that all conditions for `kGameAutorotationNone` are set to `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`, what do I see? Portrait.

What's is strange is that I can see Landscape Left if I instead `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` to:

```
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION==kGameAutorotationNone
    //
    // EAGLView won't be autorotated.
    // Since this method should return YES in at least 1 orientation, 
    // we return YES only in the Portrait orientation
    //
    return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
```

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect you're seeing comes from the fact that device and interface orientations are switched for the landscape orientations:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft  == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

That means your device orientation is LandscapeLeft but you don't allow the RootViewController to rotate to interface orientation LandscapeRight. Therefore it will default to Portrait mode. I suppose if you rotated your device 180° it would suddenly rotate to the device orientation LandscapeRight.

Btw, when you change the autorotation settings in GameConfig.h you don't need to make any changes to the RootViewController class.

Comment: thanks, i'm confused.. why are the device orientations switched? switched where, how? I'm not sure what you mea by the code you presented here. i appreciate the help.

Comment: actually, i think i just digested what you mean. let me try some things